# Create a menu on the left

Tags: c++, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Here: http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/ui/navigation/single_screen.html#joh1349181654901
I learned how to create an action menu on the *right*.
I would like to create a similar menu however which shows from the left.
Can someone please help how to do this?

ps. And also btw. does anyone know if it is possible to add "Sections" (or separators) to
the menu items? like:

```
UserPage
 Item1
 Item2
SettingsPage
 Item1
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible, and it's certainly not recomended. BlackBerry 10 has a rigid [UI GuideLine](https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/files/design/bb10/UI_Guidelines_BlackBerry_10.pdf) that tells *actions* shall be placed on *right*, while *tabs* are placed on the *left*.

Comment: I am thinking to create a custom menu because I think TabbedPane may not satisfy my functionality completely. i.e., the menu I am trying to implement and it will come out from left is very similar to this one: http://postimage.org/image/l3wpor19t/. So what are your recommendations, you think there maybe problems because of this? it is somewhat similar to TabbedPane (but may have a bit different functionality, it is not exactly Tabs. also the searchbar on top). what is your opinion?

Comment: pa. can you please show me also where does that guideline say that (which page etc.)? Thank you.

Comment: It's on page 45, on the menus section. But I guess you can achieve that with TabbedPane, since you can even put icons on them. But you'd have to find another place to put the search bar.